# How to add a Group to every Instance of a Model

Tags: python, django

I've looked around and can't find a recent snippet or an example of how to assign a [`group`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Group) to a model in Django. My project has companies and students I wanted to use decorators to only allow companies to run certain views. The best way I found was to assign my company model a group called company for example and then use a decorator like:
I've already created the group in the site admin.

```
@group_required('company')
def myview(request, id):
...
```

My Company Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank= False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So I can I assign every object of class Company to a group? Other solutions are also appreciated.

Comment: What is it you don't like about this solution?

Comment: Well I haven't yet assigned this model to a group. My question is how to to that.

Comment: you first must decide on your relationship ... is it one to one (probably not), or ManyToOne(Maybe) or is it ManyToMany(probably) ... you may want to look at something like django_organisations as I think you are trying to reimplement their library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is a `User` behind your company you can use django's inbuilt group management.

Add a user to a group:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
g = Group.objects.get(name='company') 
g.user_set.add(your_user)
```

Then you can use the `user_passes_test` decorator to allow access to a view only for members of the group `company`

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='company').exists())
def company_view(request):
    ...
```

### EDIT:

To add every company-user automatically to the company group you can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/). This will run after the `Company` models `save` method.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Company)
def chat_entry_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        g = Group.objects.get(name='company') 
        g.user_set.add(instance.user)
```

Comment: So every time I a user is created that code is run write? Is it impossible to do that association in a model level instead of object level?

Comment: I edited my question. To automatically create a group entry you can use `signals`. I'm not sure what you mean with `model level`.

Comment: I am in kind of similar situation. I want managers to create a instance of a model and their respective employees should be able to access their managers model instance. How do i do it for class based views?